# Using reference to nonexistent value sets variable to NULL?

Tags: php, variables, null

When passing a non-existent value by reference, PHP creates the value and sets it to NULL. I noticed it when memory increases were occurring while checking empty values in some functions. Take the following function:

```
function v(&$v,$d=NULL){return isset($v)?$v:$d;}
$bar = v($foo, $default);
```

This would be shorthand for:

```
if(isset($foo))
{
    $bar = $foo;
}
else
{
    $bar = $default;
}
```

However, when passing non-existent variables PHP creates them. In the case of variables - they are removed as soon as the method/function ends - but for checking super global arrays like $_GET or $_POST the array element is never removed causing extra memory usage.

```
$request_with = v($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']);
```

**Can anyone explain why this happens and if it is a PHP todo fix or a feature for some other crazy use of values?**

Comment: PHP 5.3.x on Debian, Ubuntu, and Windows XP running PHPFastcgi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you have the memory leak, is because you're telling it to.

When you ask for a reference parameter, PHP will provide you with one.  When you are calling a function with an unset variable, PHP will set the variable and then pass the reference to that new variable.  When you call it with a superglobal, it creates the missing index.  That's because you told it to.

However, I must ask why specifically do you need variable references?  99.9% of the time you don't really need them.  I suspect that it'll work just fine to do:

```
function v($v, $d = null) { return isset($v) ? $v : $d; }
```

Or, if you really must use references (which you can't get around your original problem with), you should also return a reference:

```
function &v(&$v, $d = null) { 
    if (isset($v)) {
        return $v;
    }
    return $d;
}
```

Otherwise it's pointless to take a reference and not return one...

Comment: Pointless indeed. My only guess is that he thinks he's saving resources by not passing by value. Unfortunately, he's unaware of COW (copy-on-write).

Comment: I'm aware of COW, saving memory isn't the point of the function. Dealing with non-existent values is. however, `function &v(){...}` is invalid PHP: `Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference` which is why it's written like it is. In other words, references are the only way to deal with unset values without causing PHP to error.

Answer (score 3):

XeonCross' function v is a shorthand for the often used:

```
$val= isset($arr['elm']) ? $arr['elm'] : 'default'
```

to avoid the dreaded 'Undefined index: elm' notice. A nice helper function would be:

```
function ifset(&$v1, $v2 = null) {
    return isset($v1) ? $v1 : $v2;
}
```

as Xeoncross suggested, so you could write the much nicer

```
$val = ifset($arr['elm'],'default')
```

however, this has a lot of interesting (?) quirks in our beloved "language" that we call PHP:

inside the function ifset, $v1 seems UNSET, so it correctly returns the value $v2 and you might conclude that ifset works ok. But afterwards $arr['elm'] is silently set to NULL. So consider the following:

```
    function wtf(&$v) {
       if (isset($v))
           echo "It is set";
       else
           echo "It is NOT set";
    }
    $p=[];
    wtf($p['notexist']);   => It is NOT set
    $p;                    => [ 'notexist' => NULL ]
```

But this is another delusion, as the isset() function returns false for NULL values as well:

```
$x=NULL;
isset($x)   => false... huh??
```

Did we expect this? well.. it is in the documentation, so this is by design as well. Welcome to the wonderful world of php.

Comment: I also created a method exactly like this one. And then I lost half of the day trying to figure out what is creating crappy data in my arrays. :/